# Speed z3-solver up with right tactics

Tags: z3, z3py

I create about 20k constraints and on my machine it takes about 3 minutes to solve them. I have  different kind of constraints and below I give examples and explain them. I uploaded the assertions to http://filebin.ca/vKcV1gvuGG3.

I'm interested in solving larger constraint systems, thus I'd like to speed the process up. I would like to ask if you have suggestions on how to solve them faster e.g. by using appropriate tactics. From the tutorial on strategies I know the tactics, but I don't seem to get a positive difference by applying tactics...

The `li` are labels of a tree. The 1st type makes restrictions on the values of the labels. The label-values typically range between 10-20 different values.

```
Or(l6 == 11, Or(l6 == 0, l6 == 1, l6 == 2, l6 == 3, l6 == 4,
      l6 == 5, l6 == 6, l6 == 7, l6 == 8, l6 == 9, l6 == 10))
```

The 2nd type relates different labels to each other.

```
Implies(l12 == 0, Or(l10 == 2, l10 == 5, l10 == 7, l10 == 8, l10 == 10,
           False, False))
```

The 3rd type defines and relates functions `f: Int --> Int` (or `f: BitVector --> BitVector`, at loss of completeness), where `bound_{s, v}` is just a function name, and `n` is an ID of a node. The goal is to find a satisfying assignment to the functions `bound`.

```
Implies(And(bound_s_v (18) >= 0, l18 == 0),
        And(bound_s_v (19) >= 0,
            bound_s_v (19) >=
            bound_s_v (18),
            bound_s_v (26) >= 0,
            bound_s_v (26) >=
            bound_s_v (18)))
```

The last type determines if a bound is required (`>= 0`) or not (`== -1`, )

```
Or(bound_s'_v'(0) >= 0, bound_s'_v'(0) == -1)
```

Also there is a requirement that for some initial state the bound is required:

```
`bound_s0_v0(0) >= 0`
```

**Description of the exutable file:** In the first 2-3 lines the script initiates the solver, imports z3 and in the last line calls `print s.check()`

Comment: The file you posted is truncated. We can't execute it. The declarations are missing. For example, it does not contain the declaration of `l6`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I made the file executable now.

Answer (score 0):

Presumbaly, you could try to use solver 'qflia', since I see no quantifier in your logic.

**Edit:**

I tried 'qflia', but it didn't make it faster. Maybe, you should try other solvers as well.